# PyBind11: Returning a const reference to std::vector of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pybind11

I am attempting to return a const reference to a vector of unique ptrs from a C++ library to a python interface. I am trying code similar to the below, but I am getting compilation errors when trying to call `py::bind_vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>>`

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>

class A
{
  public:
    A( int x ){ i = x; }
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    int getI() { return i; }

  private:
    int i;
};

class Test
{
  public:
    Test(){
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        avec_.emplace_back( std::make_unique<A>(i));
      }
    }
    Test( const Test& ) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test& ) = delete;

    const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>& getVec() const { return avec_; }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> avec_;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(UniqContainer, m) {

  py::bind_vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>>(m, "VecA", py::module_local() );

  py::class_<A>(m, "A")
    .def( py::init<int>() )
    .def( "getI", &A::getI );

  py::class_<Test>(m, "Test" )
    .def( py::init<>() )
    .def( "getVec", &Test::getVec, py::return_value_policy::reference_internal );
}
```

My question is - is it possible to return a const reference to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` in python bindings?

EDIT:
Added:

- copy ctor and assignment operator delete
- `py::return_value_policy::reference_internal`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53807492/955273

Comment: I did try that and unfortunately it did not resolve the issue. I left it out of my example for brevity however, I should have made note..

Comment: Most likely what you need it setting `return_value_policy::reference_internal` as the return policy. If you have tried that and it didn't work update the question with this information such that we can help you finding out why it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the compiler errors are coming from the call to `py::bind_vector` so that is not the issue. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the best I can come up with. It might have life-span issues, if you save handles to the instances of A in python and then delete them in c++. You can't use reference_internal in the context that I'm using it because it doesn't know what lifespan is being referred to. You might be able to explicitly add `py::keep_alive` to the function def as well to keep things in scope. I don't know what you're lifetime requirements are and I'm still a little hazy on that part of the API.

```
  py::class_<Test>(m, "Test" )
    .def( py::init<>() )
    .def( "getVec",
          [](const Test& obj) {
            auto pylist = py::list();
            for (auto& ptr : obj.getVec()) {
              auto pyobj = py::cast(*ptr, py::return_value_policy::reference);
              pylist.append(pyobj);
            }
            return pylist;
          });
}
```

Basically, have to manually create the `py::list` and then cast the smart pointers in it to `py::object` by reference to populate the list.

(note, I also removed the `py::bind_vector` to make everything compile)